# MongoDB C# drivers throws ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: serverVersion

Tags: c#, mongodb

MongoDB C# driver is throwing an ArgumentNullException for the parameter serverVersion on the code below. However, my code does not have any call to MongoDB that seems directly related to this parameter (or the SemanticVersion object in general). I have a code snippet below which exemplifies what I am doing.

This snippet runs in a microservice and actually works most of the time, however on the specific circumstance when this exception is thrown, my microservice is being moved across different instances, and the exception is thrown in my old instance. My expectation was that my code should handle the consistency in situations like that, so I was not expecting any specific error from MongoDB.

```
    FilterDefinition<MyMongoObject> filter = Builders<MyMongoObject>.Filter.Eq(nameof(MyMongoObject.Id), id);
    List<MyMongoObject> mongoResult = await this.mongoCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

    if (mongoResult.Count > 1) ...
```

Note that I am not sure if the exception is due to a consistency check, I only suspect since this code works fine during regular calls (i.e. when my main instance is not being decommissioned/moved).

Below is the stack trace in the exception, from the ToListAsync() call:

```
    Error when syncing to Query StoreSystem.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: serverVersion
       at MongoDB.Driver.ReadConcern.ThrowIfNotSupported(SemanticVersion serverVersion)
       at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindCommandOperation`1.CreateCommand(ServerDescription serverDescription)
       at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindCommandOperation`1.<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__110.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindCommandOperation`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__107.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__107.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.<ExecuteReadOperationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<ExecuteReadOperationAsync>d__59`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__16`1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: could you show code where you define mongo collection?

Comment: await mongoDatabase.CreateCollectionAsync("mycollection");

IMongoCollection<MyMongoObject> mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<MyMongoObject>("mycollection");

Comment: I'm seeing this message now as well. Trying some volume testing. Did you figure this one out?